# Protecting specific request types, restful API, Laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I want to protect only POST requests to my index, how can I do it?

```
public $restful = true;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); 
            //this does not work
    $this->filter('before', 'auth')->only(array('post_index'));
}

public function get_index()
{
            //I do not want to protect this
    return Response::eloquent(Model::all()); 
}

public function post_index()
{
            //I want to protect only this call
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there! If you only want to protect the POST request, use a combination of the `only()` and `on()` methods. Try:

```
$this->filter('before', 'auth')->only('index')->on('post');
```

Here's the [api page](http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Routing.Filter_Collection.html#_on) for reference.